# Question about distance, open and closed sets in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $(E,d)$ a metric space, and $\emptyset\neq A,B\subset E$

My first question, when $A\subset B$ we have that $d(x,A)\leq d(x,B)$ or the inverse ?

My second question is how to prove that  $\Omega$ is open and $F$ is closed, where $$\Omega=\{x\in E; d(x,A)< d(x,B)\}; F=\{x\in E, d(x,A)\leq d(x,B)\}.$$
Please, thank you.

Comment: If you can prove $\Omega$ is open, then clearly $F$ is closed because $F^{c}$, the complement of $F$, is open, since the complement is of the same form as $\Omega$, which you will prove is open.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question:

By definition we have that for $x\in (E,d)$ , $d(x,A)=\inf\{d(x,a):a\in A\}$ and $d(x,B)=\inf\{d(x,b):b\in B\}$.

So, if $A\subset B$, then $d(x,B)\leq d(x,A)$ if $x\in E\setminus  B$.

It could be the case that $x\in B\subset E$, in which case $d(x,B)=0$ and so $d(x,A)\geq d(x,B)$.

But it could also be the case that $x\in A\subset E$, in which case $d(x,A)=0$, in which case $d(x,A)= d(x,B)$.

We see that the three conditions above just simplify to $d(x,B)\leq d(x,A)$, for $x\in E$.

Comment: $x\in A$ then $d(x,A)=0$ but since $A\subset B$ $d(x,B)=0$ then we have $d(x,A)=d(x,B)$ in this case

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: "..only if $x\in E-B$"? No, always.

Comment: @drhab ?? i don't understand

Comment: @Vrouvrou: That was my mistake. All three "cases", give the same result. We will always have that $$d(x,B)\leq d(x,A)$$

Comment: @SujaanKunalan please how to explain that the infimum on the big set is less or equal then the small set ? please

Answer (score 1):

$d\left(x,B\right)=\inf\left\{ d\left(x,y\right)\mid y\in B\right\} \leq\inf\left\{ d\left(x,y\right)\mid y\in A\right\} =d\left(x,A\right)$.

This as a consequence of $\left\{ d\left(x,y\right)\mid y\in A\right\} \subseteq\left\{ d\left(x,y\right)\mid y\in B\right\} $
wich on its turn is a consequence of $A\subset B$.

The function $x\mapsto d\left(x,A\right)$ and $x\mapsto d\left(x,B\right)$
can be shown to be continuous.

Then $f$ prescribed by $x\mapsto d\left(x,A\right)-d\left(x,B\right)$
is continuous so the preimages under $f$ of the open set $\left(-\infty,0\right)$
and the closed set $\left(-\infty,0\right]$ are open resp. closed.

These preimages are in this order the sets $\Omega$ and
$F$.

---

**Addendum**:

Here a way to prove that function $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ is indeed continuous.

For each $a\in A$ we have $d\left(x,a\right)\leq d\left(x,y\right)+d\left(y,a\right)$.
Taking the infinum over set $A$ on both sides results in $d\left(x,A\right)\leq d\left(x,y\right)+d\left(y,A\right)$.

By symmetry also $d\left(y,A\right)\leq d\left(x,y\right)+d\left(x,A\right)$.

Based on these two facts
we find: $$\left|d\left(x,A\right)-d\left(y,A\right)\right|\leq d\left(x,y\right)$$
This makes it possible to prove that the function is continuous by means of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method.

Comment: can we use the sequences ?please

Comment: In what context do you want to use sequences? To prove what?

Comment: To prove that $F$ is closed how to use the sequences, it meanse if a sequence in $F$ converge then it's limit is in $F$ ?

Comment: Let $\left(x_{n}\right)$ be a sequence in $F$ converging to $x$.
Then $d\left(x_{n},A\right)\rightarrow d\left(x,A\right)$ and $d\left(x_{n},B\right)\rightarrow d\left(x,B\right)$
because of continuity. This with $d\left(x_{n},A\right)\leq d\left(x_{n},B\right)$
for each $n$. Consequently $d\left(x,A\right)\leq d\left(x,B\right)$
or equivalently $x\in F$.

Comment: if i replace $d(x,B)$ by a real strictly positive constante $alpha$ noting change on the proof no ?

Comment: No. In fact then you are proving that $\left\{ x\in E\mid d\left(x,B\right)\leq\alpha\right\} $
is a closed set. Btw, this is true for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.
The only point is to prove that function $x\mapsto d\left(x,A\right)$
is a continuous function. Can you do that?

Comment: I have to prove that $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall X,X_1\in E^2, |(x,y)-(x_1,y_1)|\leq \delta\Rightarrow |d(x,y)-d(x_1,y_1)|<\varepsilon$

Comment: I have added something and hope that's enough. This is my last comment on this.